# Updating State, but not re-rendering in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React and am just getting my feet wet. I'm having a hard time understand why this isn't re-rending the List.  Here is my code:

app.jsx

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      links: ['test ']
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className = "row">
      <Submission linkStore = {this.state.links}/>
      <List links = {this.state.links} />
    </div>

  }
});

var element = React.createElement(Hello, {});
ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

In my submission.jsx I have this function to push info into the `links` array

```
  handleSubmitClick: function() {
    this.props.linkStore.push(this.props.text)
    this.setState({text: ''})
    console.log(this.props.linkStore)
  }
```

My list.jsx looks like this

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      links: this.props.links
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.links}
    </div>
  }
});
```

Everything works as intended and I can get the test to show appropriately.

I am aware that this isn't going to show up as an actual list and that I should create a list component to show the items in list form.  I'm just trying to run tests along the way to see how everything works.

Comment: Hi, to pass value from children to parent, your need to declare callback function that is triggered in child to update parent state. Never update `props` but state and pass data child -> parent with callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parent `state` instead of child `props`.

try this

app.jsx

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      links: ['test ']
    }
  },
  handleListSubmitClick: function(params) {
      this.setState({links:params});
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className = "row">
      <Submission linkStore = {this.state.links} handleListSubmitClick={this.handleListSubmitClick}/>
      <List links = {this.state.links} />
    </div>

  }
});
```

submission.jsx

```
handleSubmitClick: function() {
    var linkStore = this.props.linkStore;
    linkStore.push(this.props.text)
    this.setState({text: ''})
    this.props.handleListSubmitClick(linkStore);
  }
```

but I don't understand `this.props.text`. input's value using this.refs.`ref`

list.jsx

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      links: this.props.links
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.links}
    </div>
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked...thank you very much! I understand why it works as well